# Bootsrap Show Password, Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input, bootstrap-4

I have an issue with my bootstrap show password eye icon, only appearing half of it **I have tried everything that I can think of, including the following:**

- Removing other CSS/SCSS scripts
- Altering the append input class.

Here's My issue demo here ill add relevant code only also below:

```css
    
      
      <style type="text/scss">
     @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster);


#page {
  margin: 0 15px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 25vw;
   
}

label {
    font-size: 0.875em;
     width: 25vw;

}



// Error Messages - front end validation
.form-group.error {
    
    label.error {
        margin-top: 5px;
        color: #ee4141;   
    }
}

// Pod
// --------------------------------------------------


// Password Creation Info Box
// --------------------------------------------------
#password-info {
 margin: 20px 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
 ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
  li {
   padding: 10px 10px 10px 50px;
            margin-bottom: 1px;
            background: #f4f4f4;
   font-size: 12px;
   transition: 250ms ease;
            position: relative;
   .icon-container {
    display: inline;
    width: 50px;
    background: lighten(#428bca, 20%);
    position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                text-align: center;
    .fa {
     color: white;
                    padding-top: 10px;
                    position: relative;
                    top: 2px;
    }
   }
   .tip {
    color: #5ca6d5;
    text-decoration: underline;
   }
   &.valid {
    .icon-container {
     background-color: #18c36b;
    }
    color: darken(#18c36b, 10%);
   }
   span.invalid {
    color: #ff642e;
   }
  }
 }
}
      </style>
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://antimalwareprogram.co/LoginSys/browser-scss.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://antimalwareprogram.co/sb/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
  <link href="/sb/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
  <!--<link href="/sb/css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
  <script src="https://antimalwareprogram.co/sb/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://antimalwareprogram.co/sb/vendor/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://antimalwareprogram.co/sb/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
  <script src="/sb/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-append input-group"><input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" value="123" placeholder="password" style="display: block;"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="password" style="display: none;"><span tabindex="100" title="Click here show/hide password" class="add-on input-group-addon" style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="glyphicon icon-eye-open glyphicon-eye-open"></i></span></div>
  <style>
 leaf:before{content:"\f06c"}.fa-fire:before{content:"\f06d"}.fa-eye:before{content:"\f06e"}.fa-eye-slash:before{content:"\f070"}.fa-warning:before,.fa-exclamation-triangle:before{content:"\f071"}.fa-plane:before{content:"\f072"}.fa-calendar:before{content:"\f073"}.fa-
 sign:before{content:"\e101"}.glyphicon-gift:before{content:"\e102"}.glyphicon-leaf:before{content:"\e103"}.glyphicon-fire:before{content:"\e104"}.glyphicon-eye-open:before{content:"\e105"}.glyphicon-eye-close:before{content:"\e106"}.glyphicon-warning-sign:before{content:"\e107"}.glyphicon-plane:before{content:"\e108"}.glyphicon-calendar:before{con
     </style>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-show-password/1.0.3/bootstrap-show-password.min.js"></script>
<body class="bg-dark">
  <center><div class="container">
 <div class="form-group">
          
        </div>
    <div class="card card-register mx-auto mt-5">
      <div class="card-header">Register an Account <br>       <p>Already a member? <a href='login.php' class="" name="login" id="login">Login</a></p>
</div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <form>
    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="User Name" value="" tabindex="1">
    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email Address" value="" tabindex="2">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
       <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" tabindex="100"
data-toggle="password">
       
            <form class="validate-password" method="post" action="#">
              <fieldset class="fieldset-password">
                <!--<div id="alert-invalid-password" class="alert alert-danger hide">Please enter a valid password</div>
                <p>All checkmarks must turn green in order to proceed</p>-->
                <div id="password-info">
                  <ul>
                    <li id="length" class="invalid clearfix">
                      <span class="icon-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      </span>
                      At least 6 characters
                    </li>
                    <li id="capital" class="invalid clearfix">
                      <span class="icon-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      </span>
                      At least 1 uppercase letter
                    </li>
                    <li id="lowercase" class="invalid clearfix">
                      <span class="icon-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      </span>
                      At least 1 lowercase letter
                    </li>
                    <li id="number" class="invalid clearfix">
                      <span class="icon-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      </span>
                     <span> At least 1 number</span>
     </li>
       <li id="special" class="invalid clearfix">
                      <span class="icon-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      </span>
                     <span> At least 1 symbol</span>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
               
    
     
        
              </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
       <input type="password" name="passwordConfirm" id="passwordConfirm" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Confirm Password" tabindex="4">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
       <style>
#submit , #login {
display:inline-block;
/**other codes**/
}
       </style>
    <div class="row" id="submits">

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="5">
    
    </div>
      </div>
   </form>
 

    </div></center>

  
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#password").password('toggle');
</script>
```

**What really does work? only if i add the exact bootstrap code css does the eye work, but that also makes the rest of my sites css get screwed up! Demo of what I mean:**

```css
<style type="text/scss">
     @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster);


#page {
  margin: 0 15px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 25vw;
   
}

label {
    font-size: 0.875em;
     width: 25vw;

}



// Error Messages - front end validation
.form-group.error {
    
    label.error {
        margin-top: 5px;
        color: #ee4141;   
    }
}

// Pod
// --------------------------------------------------


// Password Creation Info Box
// --------------------------------------------------
#password-info {
 margin: 20px 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
 ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
  li {
   padding: 10px 10px 10px 50px;
            margin-bottom: 1px;
            background: #f4f4f4;
   font-size: 12px;
   transition: 250ms ease;
            position: relative;
   .icon-container {
    display: inline;
    width: 50px;
    background: lighten(#428bca, 20%);
    position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                text-align: center;
    .fa {
     color: white;
                    padding-top: 10px;
                    position: relative;
                    top: 2px;
    }
   }
   .tip {
    color: #5ca6d5;
    text-decoration: underline;
   }
   &.valid {
    .icon-container {
     background-color: #18c36b;
    }
    color: darken(#18c36b, 10%);
   }
   span.invalid {
    color: #ff642e;
   }
  }
 }
}
      </style>
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://antimalwareprogram.co/LoginSys/browser-scss.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://antimalwareprogram.co/sb/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
  <link href="/sb/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
  <!--<link href="/sb/css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://antimalwareprogram.co/sb/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://antimalwareprogram.co/sb/vendor/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://antimalwareprogram.co/sb/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
  <script src="/sb/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-append input-group"><input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" value="123" placeholder="password" style="display: block;"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="password" style="display: none;"><span tabindex="100" title="Click here show/hide password" class="add-on input-group-addon" style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="glyphicon icon-eye-open glyphicon-eye-open"></i></span></div>
  <style>
 leaf:before{content:"\f06c"}.fa-fire:before{content:"\f06d"}.fa-eye:before{content:"\f06e"}.fa-eye-slash:before{content:"\f070"}.fa-warning:before,.fa-exclamation-triangle:before{content:"\f071"}.fa-plane:before{content:"\f072"}.fa-calendar:before{content:"\f073"}.fa-
 sign:before{content:"\e101"}.glyphicon-gift:before{content:"\e102"}.glyphicon-leaf:before{content:"\e103"}.glyphicon-fire:before{content:"\e104"}.glyphicon-eye-open:before{content:"\e105"}.glyphicon-eye-close:before{content:"\e106"}.glyphicon-warning-sign:before{content:"\e107"}.glyphicon-plane:before{content:"\e108"}.glyphicon-calendar:before{con
     </style>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-show-password/1.0.3/bootstrap-show-password.min.js"></script>
<body class="bg-dark">
  <center><div class="container">
 <div class="form-group">
          
        </div>
    <div class="card card-register mx-auto mt-5">
      <div class="card-header">Register an Account <br>       <p>Already a member? <a href='login.php' class="" name="login" id="login">Login</a></p>
</div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <form>
    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="User Name" value="" tabindex="1">
    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email Address" value="" tabindex="2">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
       <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" tabindex="100"
data-toggle="password">
       
            <form class="validate-password" method="post" action="#">
              <fieldset class="fieldset-password">
                <!--<div id="alert-invalid-password" class="alert alert-danger hide">Please enter a valid password</div>
                <p>All checkmarks must turn green in order to proceed</p>-->
                <div id="password-info">
                  <ul>
                    <li id="length" class="invalid clearfix">
                      <span class="icon-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      </span>
                      At least 6 characters
                    </li>
                    <li id="capital" class="invalid clearfix">
                      <span class="icon-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      </span>
                      At least 1 uppercase letter
                    </li>
                    <li id="lowercase" class="invalid clearfix">
                      <span class="icon-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      </span>
                      At least 1 lowercase letter
                    </li>
                    <li id="number" class="invalid clearfix">
                      <span class="icon-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      </span>
                     <span> At least 1 number</span>
     </li>
       <li id="special" class="invalid clearfix">
                      <span class="icon-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      </span>
                     <span> At least 1 symbol</span>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
               
    
     
        
              </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
       <input type="password" name="passwordConfirm" id="passwordConfirm" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Confirm Password" tabindex="4">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
       <style>
#submit , #login {
display:inline-block;
/**other codes**/
}
       </style>
    <div class="row" id="submits">

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="5">
    
    </div>
      </div>
   </form>
 

    </div></center>

  
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#password").password('toggle');
</script>
```

**Relevent code:**

## Password Input Field

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" tabindex="100" data-toggle="password">
</div>
    </div>
       </div>
```

## Bootstrap CDN CSS I use:

```
<style>
    leaf:before{content:"\f06c"}.fa-fire:before{content:"\f06d"}.fa-
    eye:before{content:"\f06e"}.fa-eye-slash:before{content:"\f070"}.fa-
    warning:before,.fa-exclamation-triangle:before{content:"\f071"}.fa-
    plane:before{content:"\f072"}.fa-calendar:before{content:"\f073"}.fa-
    sign:before{content:"\e101"}.glyphicon-
    gift:before{content:"\e102"}.glyphicon-
    leaf:before{content:"\e103"}.glyphicon-
    fire:before{content:"\e104"}.glyphicon-eye-
    open:before{content:"\e105"}.glyphicon-eye-
    close:before{content:"\e106"}.glyphicon-warning-
    sign:before{content:"\e107"}.glyphicon-
    plane:before{content:"\e108"}.glyphicon-calendar:before{con
</style>
```

## Demo Of just The one input:

```html
<style>
 leaf:before{content:"\f06c"}.fa-fire:before{content:"\f06d"}.fa-eye:before{content:"\f06e"}.fa-eye-slash:before{content:"\f070"}.fa-warning:before,.fa-exclamation-triangle:before{content:"\f071"}.fa-plane:before{content:"\f072"}.fa-calendar:before{content:"\f073"}.fa-
 sign:before{content:"\e101"}.glyphicon-gift:before{content:"\e102"}.glyphicon-leaf:before{content:"\e103"}.glyphicon-fire:before{content:"\e104"}.glyphicon-eye-open:before{content:"\e105"}.glyphicon-eye-close:before{content:"\e106"}.glyphicon-warning-sign:before{content:"\e107"}.glyphicon-plane:before{content:"\e108"}.glyphicon-calendar:before{con
     </style>
        <link href="https://antimalwareprogram.co/sb/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://antimalwareprogram.co/sb/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-show-password/1.0.3/bootstrap-show-password.min.js"></script>
<body class="bg-dark">
  <center><div class="container">
 
    <div class="card card-register mx-auto mt-5">
     
      <div class="card-body">
        <form>
    
    
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
       <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" tabindex="100"
data-toggle="password">
```

---

## [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q1zyx56s/) With Just Input field

---

***Note:*** **It works only when a ad blocker is enabled but only shows a emoji then!**

---

***Another Note:*** **With Font Awesome, it doesnt show anything with ad blocker, but without it is still half an eye!**

Comment: You're not closing your `<div>`s, which is probably mucking things up.

Comment: I did try once but that just messed things up even more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bootstrap css that you are including is different to the JS that you are including. Use the official CDN: `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Also, make sure you close all your tags. Unclosed tags can do strange things to the layout.

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sveynh3z/

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for being late to the party but I see that some of the snippets here don't appear to be working correctly so here's my one. Should it be of any use.

If you're getting an error viewing the snippet (using Chrome), [please use the JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/nyl2k8/zkrypfv6/)

```js
var timeoutId = 0;

    $('#check').on('mousedown', function() {
        $('#eye').removeClass( "glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close" );
        $('#eye').addClass( "glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" );
        $('#password').attr('type', 'text');
        timeoutId = setTimeout(1000);
    }).on('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
        $('#password').attr('type', 'password');
        $('#eye').removeClass( "glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" );
        $('#eye').addClass( "glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close" );
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h3>Show Password Example:</h3>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
                      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="check"><span id="eye" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        </span>
      </div>
      <!-- /input-group -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
  </div>
</div>
```